Long term file access on Avalonia cross platform application
I am trying to make an Avalonia cross platform application that lets you pick one or multiple images with a file picker. Once the images are selected, i store the file path into a collection that the user can access later and i create a thumbnail for the collection.
At some point in the application, the user can select this collection and i want to display the images he previously selected.
This is the code that i use to pick one or multiple files:
 public async void addLibraryFromFilesEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
 {
     // Get top level from the current control. Alternatively, you can use Window reference instead.
     var topLevel = TopLevel.GetTopLevel(this);

     // Start async operation to open the dialog.
     var files = await topLevel.StorageProvider.OpenFilePickerAsync(new FilePickerOpenOptions
     {
         Title = "Select one or more images",
         AllowMultiple = true,
         FileTypeFilter = [FilePickerFileTypes.ImageAll]
     });

     if (files.Count <= 0)
     {
         return;
     }

     LibraryItem library = new LibraryItem();

     // The list of paths to the selected files
     library.paths = new List<string>();

     for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
     {
         // Checking if the selected file is an image
         if (SessionManager.ImageExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(files[i].Path.ToString()).ToUpperInvariant()))
         {
             library.paths.Add(files[i].Path.ToString());
         }
     }

     // Path to the first image selected, that i use to create a thumbnail
     string originalCoverImagePath = library.paths[0];
     library.coverImagePath = new Uri("path/to/library/" + library.id + Path.GetExtension(originalCoverImagePath)).AbsoluteUri;

     // I create an avalonia IStorageFile object in order to read the image
     IStorageFile originalCoverImage = await topLevel.StorageProvider.TryGetFileFromPathAsync(new Uri(originalCoverImagePath));

     using (Stream coverStream = await originalCoverImage.OpenReadAsync())
     {
         Bitmap cover = new Bitmap(coverStream);
         double width = cover.Size.Width;
         double height = cover.Size.Height;
         int destinationHeight = 200;

         double wRatio = width / height;
         // Create scaled bitmap for the thumbnail
         Bitmap libraryThumbnail = cover.CreateScaledBitmap(new PixelSize((int)(destinationHeight * wRatio), destinationHeight));

         Uri coverImageUri = new Uri(library.coverImagePath);
         IStorageFolder thumbnailFolder = await topLevel.StorageProvider.TryGetFolderFromPathAsync(new Uri(PreferencesHandler.thumbnailsFolderPath));

         libraryThumbnail.Save("path/to/library/" + library.id + Path.GetExtension(originalCoverImagePath));

         PreferencesHandler.writeLibraryFile();
     }
 }

This works perfectly on desktopp, but on android the app crashes because it says i need to obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs. How do i handle the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT from the library project where the shared code resides?
These are the permissions given in the manifest:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
              android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

I have read that MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is a risky permission, and google play doesnt always allow it, so i would like to avoid using it.
Also, i have seen other applications do a similar thing, and in the file dialog they open on android, it says "application will only have access to the files you select", while in the avalonia file picker, it doesnt say it whatsoever, and the picker seems to be of a completely different kind, so i wonder if there is another way to do it or not.

NOTE
A weird behaviour i noticed, is that ONLY SOME IMAGES are able to be selected and EVEN displayed when accessed later. But the majority of images throw that error both when creating the thumbnail and when accessing them later. I am talking about images in the same folder!
What can be the cause of only some images being able to be read?
EDIT:
If i remove the android:targetSdkVersion="31" and set the target sdk to 33, trying to open files throws the error that i need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, even though on version 33 that is not used anymore

Following what's written in the documentation you need to invoke an intent (in your case, the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) and use that to allow the user to select one or multiple documents, your app cannot just go and read files arbitrarily.

But i do not have access to android code in the "library" project of avalonia, since that is then compiled depending on the platform. The intent here is handled by avalonia if i am not mistaken
